# Unpivot multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, unpivot

I want to unpivot 2 rows at the same time and keep each field associated with the field above/below it.

[Current table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LVCd.png)

| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| unwanted | unwanted | unwanted | unwanted | unwanted | unwanted |
| Point_ID | Easting | Northing | Height | Azimuth | Inclination |
| NA | metres | metres | metres | degress | degrees |

[Desired table format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STOgu.png)

| col | units |
| --- | --- |
| Point_ID | NA |
| Easting | metres |
| Northing | metres |
| Height | metres |
| Azimuth | degrees |
| Inclination | degrees |

So far I have:
 `SELECT col FROM table1 UNPIVOT ( col for cols in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]) AS table1Unpivot`

But this just puts everything into 1 column and I not sure on how to get the second desired column.
The col names (Point_ID, easting etc.) may change order but will always have consistent names and will always be directly above their associated unit.

Can anyone please let me know the best way to go about this, thanks!

Schema:

```
`CREATE TABLE [dbo].[table1](
    [1] [nvarchar](99) NULL,
    [2] [nvarchar](99) NULL,
    [3] [nvarchar](99) NULL,
    [4] [nvarchar](99) NULL,
    [5] [nvarchar](99) NULL,
    [6] [nvarchar](99) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]) VALUES (N'unwanted', N'unwanted', N'unwanted', N'unwanted', N'unwanted', N'unwanted')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]) VALUES (N'Point_ID', N'Easting', N'Northing', N'Height', N'Azimuth', N'Inclination')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[table1] ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]) VALUES (N'NA', N'metres', N'metres', N'metres', N'degrees', N'degrees')
GO
`
```

Comment: If you put some sample data in as DDL+DML you'll make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Your current table doesn't make sense: how do you know which row is the one to use for `col` values and which to use for `units`? As you can see, @JohnCappelletti's answer use `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` as there is no way of identifying the rows

Comment: The row of 'cols' is always directly above the row of 'units' - it's being imported from external inconsistent files so unfortunately I don't have much control over this. I could insert an extra column to the left of the table to act as a 'row heading' i.e it will say 'col' or 'units' for each row - if this would help?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an UNPIVOT with conditional aggregation

**Example**

```
 Select col  =max(case when rn=1 then value end)
       ,units=max(case when rn=2 then value end)
  From  (
            Select * 
             From (Select *
                          ,rn=row_number() over(order by (select null)) 
                     From YourTable 
                     Where [1]<>'unwanted' ) src
             UnPivot ( value for item in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]) ) unpiv
        ) A
 Group by item
```

**Returns**

```
col          units
Point_ID     NA
Easting      metres
Northing     metres
Height       metres
Azimuth      degress
Inclination  degrees
```

Comment: `over(order by (select null))` could return anything, how do you know the `rn` values are the correct ones?